# How to determine bandwidth used by cron job?

Tags: cron

I'm not a unix guy. CPanel does a good job of managing cronjobs and that is what I used to run dozens of cronjobs. All of them combined run more than 5000 times *every day*. Every cron makes a call to an external API.

How can I check how much bandwidth are all the cron jobs eating? For my website I use awstats and that shows bandwidth usage et al.

Another thing is that I dont want the admins to ban the cron jobs because they are using too much bandwidth (and CPU), more than what is allocated in my web hosting package.

Comment: The best way to tell without a analytics program would be copying all your cronjobs and files to a Temporary subdomain and checking through that (not visinting them). This would give you EXACT time for the cronjob. You can then run seperate cronjobs on subdomain of the subdomain to find out each individually. You may need to copy over a database and files needed to run the cronjobs but you can delete these after and the accurate results are very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look at the bandwidth used for individual API calls.

At least I am not aware of a utility that can do b/w analysis at process/thread level. It's at network layer.

Comment: As long as the admins are not alerted by the CPU usage or the bandwidth usage, all is good. I wanted to know this stats myself before they did!

Comment: Not sure... but may find some trick in Eucalyptus. You'll have to explore yourself. Eucalyptus is open-source cloud (like EC2) and has CPU + bandwidth thresholds.

Answer (score 1):

You can do all kinds of crazy things with netcat.  See http://pauldotcom.com/wiki/index.php/Episode195#Instrumented_Relays for some examples.  Combine with tee and wc to count actual bytes passed.